# gunicorn socket EPIPE

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, netcat

Why there is some difference when testing by curl and nc?
Load balance using the command nc to check whether gunicorn is ok. But its reponse code is not 2xx or 3xx when using "nc". 4xx is considered to be unhealthy.

Some config:

nginx-gunicorn.conf

```
upstream app_server {
server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen 8086;
    server_name 192.168.1.2;
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
    access_log   logs/gunicorn.access.log;
    error_log     logs/gunicorn.error.log;
    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host "${host}:${server_port}";
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

gunicorn.conf.py

```
bind="unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock"
workers = 1
pidfile = "/ebs/var/gunicorn/pidx.file"
loglevel = "debug"
accesslog = "/ebs/var/log/gunicornx_access.log"
errorlog = "/ebs/var/log/gunicornx_error.log"
pythonpath = "/ebs/zh/test_host1"
worker_connections = 200
max_requests = 1024
keepalive = 3
preload_app = True
```

supervisord.conf

```
[program:gunicorn]
command=/ebs/zh/bin/gunicorn -c /ebs/zh/test_host1/gunicorn.conf.py wsgi:application
directory=/ebs/zh/test_host1/test_host1
numprocs = 1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile = /ebs/var/log/workers/test.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 10KB
stdout_logfile_backups = 5
stderr_logfile = /ebs/var/log/workers/test.log
```

1. Test using curl

Information:

```
curl -I 192.168.1.2:8086/index
HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
Server: st/
Date: Thu, 01 Feb 2018 19:33:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://192.168.1.2:8086/index/
```

gunicorn_error.log(gunicorn)

```
2018-02-01 13:33:37 [8221] [DEBUG] HEAD /index
```

gunicorn.access.log(nginx)

```
192.168.1.3 - - [02/Feb/2018:03:33:37 +0800] "HEAD /index HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.26.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18"
```

2. Test using nc

Information

```
echo -e 'HEAD /index HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n' | nc -w 192.168.1.2 8086
```

gunicorn_error.log(gunicorn)

```
2018-02-01 12:40:58 [16203] [DEBUG] HEAD /index
2018-02-01 12:40:58 [16203] [DEBUG] Ignoring EPIPE
```

gunicorn.access.log(nginx)

```
192.168.1.3 - - [02/Feb/2018:02:57:43 +0800] "HEAD /index HTTP/1.0" 499 0 "-" "-"
```